# SSLException when server cert uses SAN (Subject Alternative Name)

Tags: android, ssl

I'm trying to establish a https connection using the classes in org.apache.http.*.  As part of my setup, I'm using the BrowserCompatHostnameVerifier() class which states:

> *The hostname must match either the first CN, or any of the subject-alts. A wildcard can occur in the CN, and in any of the subject-alts.*

When I hit a server who's hostname doesn't match that which is specified in the CN but does match one of the entries in the subject-alts, I get the following exception:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match: <mtvniph1-f.akamaihd.net> != <a248.e.akamai.net>
     at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:222)
     at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.BrowserCompatHostnameVerifier.verify(BrowserCompatHostnameVerifier.java:54)
     at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:151)
     at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:132)
     at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:321)
```

Here's the relevant code block that's causing this error:

```
DefaultHttpClient seed = new DefaultHttpClient();
SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();

SSLSocketFactory ssf = SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory();

// XXX: This verifier isn't working with Subject Alternative Names
ssf.setHostnameVerifier(new BrowserCompatHostnameVerifier());

registry.register(new Scheme("https", ssf, 443));

SingleClientConnManager mgr = new SingleClientConnManager(seed.getParams(), registry);
DefaultHttpClient http = new DefaultHttpClient(mgr, seed.getParams());

// Config point, change to your preference
String url = "https://mtvniph1-f.akamaihd.net/e3_ubisoft_prod0.m3u8";

HttpGet method = new HttpGet(url);

HttpResponse response = null;
try
{
    response = http.execute(method);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Log.e(TAG, "Request failed", e);
}
```

Compare this behavior and that when you replace the url with "https://www.google.com".  I can work around this by creating my own X509HostnameVerifier, but I want to know if this is a valid bug in BrowserCompatHostnameVerifier or if I'm doing something wrong.

Anyone else having similar issues?

Comment: Update: I tried the same code block using the Apache HttpComponents (http://hc.apache.org) v4.0.1 lib directly and I can't reproduce the behavior. This leads me to believe that it's a bug in the Android implementation of this lib.

Comment: There are two such bugs, http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17680&can=1&q=reporter%3Anathan%2Cjanrain.com&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars and another one I can't find a link to that only reads the first 16 (8?) names in the SAN extension.

Answer (score 1):

According to trunk [AbstractVerifier.java](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpcomponents/httpclient/trunk/httpclient/src/main/java/org/apache/http/conn/ssl/AbstractVerifier.java), it isn't picking up your subjectAltName (it lists all the names it finds in the exception). `openssl s_client -connect mtvniph1-f.akamaihd.net:443 -showcerts` suggests it's not a problem with the certificate.